# Python Password Generator with TKInter

Tags: python, tkinter, random, window, password-generator

I am coding a password generator with an interface for school and I can't seem to find out where to put the password generator piece in my program.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

characters = "abcdefABCDEF1234!@#$"

length = 8

window = Tk()

window.title('Password Generator')

while True:
    input("Press Enter to generate new password")
    password = "".join(random.sample(characters, length))
    print(password)

label = Label (window, print(password))

label.pack(padx = 200, pady = 50)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking where to put the label or where to put the code that generates the password? Or both? Whatever you're asking is fine, I just need clarity so I can try my best to answer.

Comment: I am asking where about where to put the code that generates the password

Comment: Np. What does the end result have to be? Something that works? Is there a requirement to use a function or something?

Comment: the end result needs to be a working password generator with a GUI and whenever you press Enter it generated a new password.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Since it is a password generator, based on your previous code and my assumption, I have made some changes to your code. It generates and displays a new password on every button click.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

characters = "abcdefABCDEF1234!@#$"

length = 8

def generatepassword():
    password = "".join(random.sample(characters, length))
    label.config(text=password)
    
window = Tk()

window.title('Password Generator')

generatebtn = Button(window,text="Click to Generate Password",command=generatepassword)
generatebtn.pack()

label = Label (window,text="")

label.pack(padx = 200, pady = 50)

window.mainloop()
```